# Firebase: Multi Location Update using Firebase Object Observable

Tags: arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to work out how to do a multi-location update using the FirebaseObjectObservable.

This is what my data looks like.

```
recipes: {
  -R1: {
    name: 'Omelette',
    ingredients: ['-I1']
  }
}

ingredients: {
  -I1: {
    name: 'Eggs',
    recipes: ['-R1']
  },
  -I2: {
    name: 'Cheese',
    recipes: []
  }
}
```

I want to then update that recipe and add an extra ingredient.

```
const recipe = this.af.database.object(`${this.path}/${key}`);
recipe.update({
  name: 'Cheesy Omelette',
  ingredients: ['-I1', '-I2']
});
```

And to do multi-location updates accordingly:

```
recipes: {
  -R1: {
    name: 'Cheesy Omelette',
    ingredients: ['-I1', '-I2'] // UPDATED
  }
}

ingredients: {
  -I1: {
    name: 'Eggs',
    recipes: ['-R1']
  },
  -I2: {
    name: 'Cheese',
    recipes: ['-R1'] // UPDATED
  }
}
```

Is this possible in Firebase? And what about the scenario where an update causes 1000 writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing your ingredients in an array makes it pretty hard to add an ingredient. This is because arrays are index-based: in order to add an item to an array, you must know how many items are already in that array.

Since that number requires a read from the database, the code becomes pretty tricky. The most optimal code I can think of is:

```
recipe.child("ingredients").orderByKey().limitToLast(1).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var updates = {};
  updates[parseNum(snapshot.key)+1] = "-I2";
  recipe.child("ingredients").update(updates);
});
```

And while this is plenty tricky to read, it's still not very good. If multiple users are trying to change the ingredients of a recipe at almost the same time, this code will fail. So you really should be using a transaction, which reads more data and hurts scalability of your app.

This is one of the reasons why [**Firebase has always recommended against using arrays**](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

A better structure to store the ingredients for a recipe is with a set. With such a structure your recipes would look like this:

```
recipes: {
  -R1: {
    name: 'Omelette',
    ingredients: { 
      "-I1": true 
    }
  }
}
```

And you can easily add a new ingredient to the recipe with:

```
recipe.update({ "ingredients/-I2": true });
```